# From second to dateTime in Azure Stream Analytics

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, t-sql, azure-stream-analytics

I want to convert 'dd' that is a number that indicate Data device (dd is in second).

At the moment I can extract the Year, Month, Day, Hour with this query in Azure Stream Analytics:

```
 DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(MILLISECOND, dd, '1970-01-01')) AS [Year],
 DATEPART(MONTH, DATEADD(MILLISECOND, dd, '1970-01-01')) AS [Month],
 DATEPART(DAY, DATEADD(MILLISECOND, dd, '1970-01-01')) AS [Day],
 DATEPART(HOUR, DATEADD(MILLISECOND, dd, '1970-01-01')) AS [Hour]
```

I want to extract the DateTime from dd, so after that i can insert on a database.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you simply need only to calculate the date from the Epoch.

```
--If dd is milliseconds NOTE : This could cause error as DATEADD does not use BIGINT for conversion

    DECLARE @MyDate DATETIME  = DATEADD(MILLISECOND, dd, '1970-01-01')

--If dd is seconds. The safer route.
    DECLARE @MyDate DATETIME = DATEADD(SECOND, dd, '1970-01-01')
```

Comment: I try this: DATETIME @MyDate = DATEADD(SECOND, dd, '1970-01-01') but not works

Comment: DECLARE @MyDate DATETIME, el typos

Answer (score 0):

stream analytics have a support for JavaScript based UDF, you can try this